# Mysql_fetch_array($sql) vs mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)

Tags: php, mysql, оптимизация, производительность

Сегодня мой мир изменился, случайным образом я узнал что mysql_fetch_array() возвращает вместе с ассоциативным массивом еще какой-то числовой и дублирует данные.

Выглядит это примерно так

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => 12
    [cid] => 12
    [2] => WcQcsdf
    [name] => WcQcsdf
 )
```

Если же получить массив через **mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)** или **mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)** то получим

```
 Array
 (
    [id] => 1
    [cid] => 12
    [name] => WcQcsdf
 )
```

Кто имел опыт c этим и знает что работает быстрее?

1. `mysql_fetch_array($sql)`
2. `mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)`
3. `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)`

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Извините за занудство, но прекратите наконец использовать расширение mysql, оно [deprecated](http://habrahabr.ru/post/124245/). mysqli и PDO проще, кроме того mysql не безопасен.

Например, раньше было

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");
mysql_select_db('my_db', $lnk)
```

Теперь стало

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Не правда ли так проще и понятнее? Я уже не говорю про биндинги и отсутствие необходимости вручную фильтровать входные параметры, все уже за вас сделано.

Вот хорошая [статья с хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141127/)

Comment: Вот как, теперь везде писать mysqli вместо mysql?

Comment: Там разница больше чем просто в названии. Это и ООП и биндинги и много чего еще классного, Вот отличная статья - http://habrahabr.ru/post/141127/

Comment: @M11 дополнил пост выше

Comment: @donkey Спасибо за ссылку, создал тему для того что бы узнать что быстрее. В итоге перехожу на mysqli в стиле ООП.)) То что фильтровать не нужно это прекрасно, только не сильно понял как все работает, ранее с ООП почти не работал. Но буду разбираться, спасибо.
ps в mysql $link можно не использовать

Comment: @donkey у меня появилась мысль. наверное есть то что делает проще при разработке mysqli, слишком много команд нужно делать для одного запроса. есть такое?

Comment: @M11 Когда люди поняли что не хотят работать с таблицами а хотят с объектами, они придумали ORM. Для того чтобы не взрывать вам мозг, посоветую познакомиться с RedBean - http://www.redbeanphp.com/ http://habrahabr.ru/post/132004/

Это супер простая ORM, главное тут не забыть что такое SQL =)

Comment: @donkey я бы остановился на том что есть. просто не хочу каждый раз писать  
    
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
    $stmt->close();
 и тд...

Comment: Так оберните это в функцию. Но RedBean таки гляньте, он ну очень прост

Answer (score 0):

Иногда полезно читать [документацию](http://www.php.su/mysql_fetch_array):

> ```
> Второй опциональный аргумент `result_type` в функции
> ```
>
> `mysql_fetch_array()` -- константа и
> может принимать следующие значения:
> `MYSQL_ASSOC`, `MYSQL_NUM` и
> `MYSQL_BOTH`. Эта возможность
> добавлена в PHP 3.0.7. **Значением по
> умолчанию является: MYSQL_BOTH**.
>
> ```
>  Используя MYSQL_BOTH, вы получите массив, состоящий как из
> ```
>
> ассоциативных индексов, так и из численных.

А что касается скорости - вряд ли это то, что долнжо вас волновать в принципе. Во всяком случае до тех пор, пока профайлер не покажет, что разница (если она будет) действительно
существенно влияет на призводительность в конкретном случае.

Comment: @klopp Я вроде показал выше что можно указывать второй аргумент MYSQL_ASSOC для mysql_fetch_array(), до того как писать тут я читал документацию. Я не знаю как формируют функции результат, но mysql_fetch_array() (Без аргумента) отдает результатов в 2 раза больше -> занимают в 2 раза больше места. Мне так кажется.

Comment: Мысль была в том, что читать документацию куда полезней **до** того, как молотить по клавиатуре :)

А что использовать - да что удобней, то и используйте.

Comment: @klopp вопрос был в том что быстрее. По сути они особо в удобности не отличаются.